# Custom event initialisation issue

Tags: c#, events

I use custom events on my graphic objects to notify of object's changes :

```
public class OnLabelWidthChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private float _width;

    public float Width
    {
        get { return _width; }
        set { _width = value; }
    }

    public OnLabelWidthChangedEventArgs(float widthParam) : base()
    {
        Width = widthParam;
    }
}
```

This is the object firing this event :

```
public class DisplayLabel : DisplayTextObject
{
    public event EventHandler<OnLabelWidthChangedEventArgs > OnLabelSizeChanged;

    public DisplayLabel(ScreenView _screenParam, IXapGraphicObject obj) : base(_screenParam, obj)
    {
        l = new Label();
        SetSize();
    }

    public override void SetSize()
    {
        Width = w;
        Height = h;
        if(OnLabelWidthChanged != null)
             OnLabelSizeChanged.Invoke(this, new OnLabelWidthChangedEventArgs(w)); //  OnLabelSizeChanged is null
    }
```

The `OnLabelSizeChanged` is always null, how can I initialise it.

I have a working solution with delegates instead of custom events:

```
 public event OnWidthChanged WidthChanged = delegate { };
```

but I'd like to know how to solve this issue with custom events.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your working solution is also a custom event.

Comment: See https://www.google.com.br/search?q=C%23+custom+events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't initialize your event, you assign a handler to it (aka. subscribing to it), something similar to this:

```
myDisplayLabel.OnLabelWidthChanged += MyEventHandlerMethod;
```

where `MyEventHandlerMethod` is a method matching the event's signature, i.e.

```
void MyEventHandlerMethod(Object sender, OnLabelWidthChangedEventArgs)
```

Bedtime reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, missed that... the delegate syntax is more compact... I think i'll use it.